Cant access Auth0 from kubernetes because of egress network policy
I have an authorization microservice that authorizes users through Auth0. My service is running in kubernetes and I've tested that it works if i disable my egress network policies but it doesn't work when they're enabled.
Below is my network policy for my authorization service, the ips are all the ips for europe, united states, and united kingdoms from https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/allowlist.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-to-auth0
  namespace: swwao-app
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: authorization
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 174.129.105.183/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.116.79.126/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.117.64.128/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.191.46.63/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.218.26.94/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.232.225.224/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.233.90.226/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.131.238.180/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.131.55.63/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.132.201.78/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.133.18.220/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.134.176.17/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.19.44.88/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.20.244.231/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.21.254.195/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.211.189.167/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 34.211.191.214/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 34.233.19.82/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 34.233.190.223/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.160.3.103/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.162.47.8/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.166.202.113/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.167.74.121/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.171.156.124/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.82.131.220/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 44.205.93.104/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 44.218.235.21/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 44.219.52.110/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.12.243.90/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.2.61.131/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.204.128.250/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.206.34.127/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.43.255.209/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.88.192.232/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.89.116.72/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.145.227.59/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.157.101.160/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.200.12.78/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.209.32.202/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.245.16.146/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.68.157.8/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.69.107.228/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.197.9.11/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.198.229.148/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.125.185.137/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.65.249.224/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.67.233.131/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.68.125.137/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.72.27.152/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.74.90.247/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 34.246.118.27/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.157.198.116/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 35.157.221.52/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.17.111.199/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.19.3.147/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.208.95.174/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.210.121.45/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.210.122.50/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.28.184.187/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.30.153.34/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 52.57.230.214/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.228.204.106/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.228.86.224/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.73.137.216/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.75.208.179/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 54.76.184.103/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 18.135.40.36/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.10.89.10/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 3.8.59.62/32
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 443

I tried using nslookup for my auth0 management APIs domain and added those but it still didn't work
